# Is root@[127.1] a syntactically valid e-mail address?

Tags: email, standards, email-validation, rfc, rfc822

Is `root@[127.1]` a syntactically valid e-mail address?

Why? Why not?

Comment: Just the fact that we are wondering is enough for me :-)

Comment: If I look at the FAQ of stackoverflow this question doesnt fit on this site.

Comment: SynerCoder: There are hundreds of questions pertaining to e-mail syntax validation on the site. Have you never written code for validating e-mail addresses?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on whether you mean addresses in the header (RFC 5322) or envelope addresses (RFC 5321), and in the latter case, whether you include <>, everything between <> (i.e. the source route), or just Mailbox.

It's **valid** according to RFC 5322, but RFC 5322 allows *loads* of fun things like *comments!* and *unicorns!* and *cake!* and *ponies!*. It's just about possible to parse them using Perl's "regular" expressions: [Mail::RFC822::Address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

It's **syntactically invalid** according to [RFC 5321 Section 4.1.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.3) since the grammar only allows address literals of the form 1.2.3.4 or with a prefix of the form "standard-tag:" (e.g. `[IPv6:::1]`). I've assumed you meant "Mailbox", i.e. everything between <> but not including the source route.

I'd use the latter definition, since an e-mail address isn't much good if my SMTP server won't accept it. (Yes, this is a bit of a horrible definition, but I don't think the internet will move away from SMTP any time soon.)

(Additionally, there's RFC 5336 a.k.a. "UTF8SMTP". I'm not aware of anyone who uses this.)

Answer (score 15):

You need to check [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-3.4.1), section 3.4.1.

> This specification is a
> revision of Request For Comments (RFC) 2822, which itself superseded
> Request For Comments (RFC) 822, "Standard for the Format of ARPA
> Internet Text Messages", updating it to reflect current practice and
> incorporating incremental changes that were specified in other RFCs.

I run your email address though http://isemail.info/ that gave the following info:

*The general result is*: **The address is only valid according to the broad definition of RFC 5322. It is otherwise invalid.**

*The specific diagnosis is*: **The domain literal is not a valid RFC 5321 address literal**

Here is the relevant passage from the email RFCs:

> domain-literal = [CFWS] "[" *([FWS] dtext) [FWS] "]" [CFWS]

*(RFC 5322 section 3.4.1)*

Answer (score 3):

No, [RFC2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) allows IP addresses to be used as domain, but you must use a valid IP address.

Your example should be `root@[127.0.0.1]`.

Comment: Additional : Using this square bracket notion is called domain-literals.

Comment: Err. `127.1` *is* a valid IP address - it is a short for `127.0.0.1`, at least in some contexts - not all utilities support it.

Comment: The grammar in the section you linked to allows `root@[foo]`. It is *syntactically* valid.

Comment: Ooops, I meant `root@[127.1]`. It allows almost everything inside the square brackets.

Comment: RFC5321 section 4.1.3 states: "For IPv4 addresses, this form uses four small decimal integers separated by dots and enclosed by brackets such as [123.255.37.2], which indicates an (IPv4) Internet Address in sequence-of-octets form."

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822) as you mention in the tags, yes, it is *syntactically valid*, because the grammar allows it. These are the relevant rules:

```
 addr-spec   =  local-part "@" domain        ; global address    
 
 domain      =  sub-domain *("." sub-domain)
 
 sub-domain  =  domain-ref / domain-literal

 domain-literal =  "[" *(dtext / quoted-pair) "]"

 dtext       =  <any CHAR excluding "[",     ; => may be folded
                 "]", "\" & CR, & including
                 linear-white-space>
```

Answer (score -3):

No,

E-mail validity has some broad definitions, if you split the address into two sections, local (before the @ sign) and domain (after the @ sign). The local part may be alpha-numeric with the following special characters ‘.’, ‘-’ and ‘_’, the local part cannot contain contiguous periods.

The domain part must meet the definition of a host name or ip address surrounded by square braces.

As your example doesn't meet the requirements for a valid host name (foo.bar), and it doesn't contain a valid IP address surrounded by square braces, it is not a valid e-mail address.

Check out the following e-mail validator code (minus the ip address validation bit) which will validate an [e-mail address](http://www.codeinthemorning.com/code-katas/solutions/email-validator/). This can be easily retrofitted to work with ip-address domain names too.

Comment: The "local part" commonly includes +, and the RFC 5321/5322 grammar also allows loads of other fun things.